# Apache httppost Android webservice return large number of XML takes times so long

Tags: java, android, xml, apache, web-services

i'm using apache httppost to get XML data from ASP.NET webservice in server.

When the number of xml records is below thousands (e.g. 400 xml) the process time is quite fast about 10 seconds, but when the number of records are thousands (e.g. 4000 xml) the process time is about like 20 minutes which is crazy.

It supposed to be 100 seconds ((4000/400) * 10) = a.k.a 1 minute and 40 seconds

I'm trying to split my query using limit and offset and place the httppost execute inside loop, but it still takes the same time

```
httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
httpParameters.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);       
HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);


httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);     
httppost = new HttpPost("http://myipaddress/servicename.asmx/" + wsFunctionName);       
httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < paramname.length; i ++){
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(paramname[i], para[i]));
}
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));           
httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
contentlen = (int) entity.getContentLength();               
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String line = "";
try {
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
        progressvalue += line.length();
        prog = (int) ((progressvalue * 100) / contentlen );
        publishProgress(new Integer[]{prog, in+1});
    }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("e", e.toString());
} finally {
    is.close();
    entity.consumeContent();
}
```

Note: Previously I didn't use the

`httpParameters.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);`

and

`httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);`

code but the process time takes so long (no difference)

**EDIT:**

The problem is not the connection, but the number of lines from XML return is so huge so the readLine process keep going until the line end.

I've change my XML return from List of Strings[] (which has so many line break) to string. previously its takes about 20 minutes, now its only 5 seconds because just need read one line.

**EDIT 2:**

Test result are really amazing,

Using conventional string += "string" takes 14 seconds, using StringBuilder it only takes 2 second.

Thanks greenapps

Comment: Well you have too find out who is taking its time. Is it the server then this has nothing to do with Android or your client.

Comment: Mesure the time from `httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);` until after the first readLine();

Comment: Tell what you see on your prograss dialog. You can see when the first line comes in. Do you have to wait that 'process tme' for the fiirst line to come in?

Comment: The response was fast, but I found out that the problem is the more xml is the more its line, so the process takes so long because doing readLine so much. Thanks for make me realize

Comment: No. That is not all. You are adding the lines to Sting result which is an expensive operation. Better use a StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); and add to that. You will see that suddenly all is quicker. Ehhh... maybe I ment a StringBuilder... yes I think I do.

Comment: Yeah I'll try StringBuilder too! thanks

Comment: Please report which is quicker. Further you have a publishProgress for every line. That is not needed. Do less. First do a test without this function to see the effect.

Comment: I've add the report, yeah StringBuilder really quick and smooth. And yeah btw i've remove the publish progress in my real code and make it indeterminable. Thanks again :D

Comment: And the 20 minutes reduce to?

Comment: 5 seconds :O, I'll add that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was large number of string concatenation.

We supposed to use `StringBuilder` instead of plain operator +=